# Discord.js + Node.js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, fs

```
          let user = message.mentions.users.first();
          if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('Вы должны упомянуть кого-нибудь, чтобы выдать АРы.').catch(console.error);

          mcash[${user.id}, ${message.guild.id}].mcash++;

          fs.writeFile("./usercash.json", JSON.stringify(mcash), err => {
          if(err) throw err;
          });

          member.roles.cache.has('899099537979899924');
          member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Банкир');
          
          let pcash = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            if(!pcash) pcash = "Не указана"
        
         const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setDescription('Пополнение из банка:', alert(mcash))
         .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/899085238955806742/899102776263573574/200.png?width=180&height=180')
         message.author.send( {embeds:[embed] });
        }});
```

> The code must retain the amount entered along with the mention. Further, the value that was written earlier was added to the variable, but an error is displayed.

Comment: ```let mcash = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./usercash.json", "utf8"));
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('Ping').catch(console.error);
mcash[${user.id}, ${message.guild.id}].mcash++;
fs.writeFile("./usercash.json", JSON.stringify(mcash), err => {
if(err) throw err;
});      
let pcash = args.slice(1).join(" ");
if(!pcash) pcash = "Не указана"
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription('Пополнение из банка:', alert(mcash))
message.author.send( {embeds:[embed] });
}});```
full code

Comment: Please don't post your code as comment in the future!

Comment: Please add some description. What is your problem? Which error is displayed? ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
mcash[${user.id}, ${message.guild.id}].mcash++;
```

The usage of `${}` only function inside of a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), the use of it isn't needed here, so it can be changed to:

```js
mcash[user.id, message.guild.id].mcash++;
```

*Note: the whole function is not given, this may be only a portion of the solution.*

Comment: ```Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'```

Comment: What is your node version and your discord.js version?
`node -v` `npm list discord.js`

Comment: `discord.js 13.3.1`

Comment: And your node version?

Comment: node.js 16.13.0

Comment: Update node to +17v